# Sql insert into determined on select option and input type=checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have the following code:

```
INSERT INTO People (Salutation, LastName, Gluten, Crustaceans, Egg, Fish, Peanut, Celery, Mustard, Sesame, Sulphite, Nuts, Soy, Lupin, Milk, Molluscs)
```

And then, an input, a select option and a list of checkboxes

```
<input name="LastName"> 
<select name=Salutation> 
<option  selected=selected hidden value="select your salutation">Please select</option>
<option value="mr">mr</option>
<option value="mrs">mrs</option>
<input type="checkbox" name="Gluten" value="Allergic">
And so on w/ the checkboxes
```

This doesn't seem to work. Is this even possible? If yes, is it possible with a`boolean`?

Comment: Can you show the real code so we can see why it really doesn't work?

Comment: @chris85 im on ipad right now, its so difficult to type

Comment: You should copy and paste, or wait until you can post a question that demonstrates the issue. As is users are just guessing at what your real code does.

Answer (score 0):

Your insert Query is incomplete,

```
 INSERT INTO People (Salutation, LastName, Gluten, Crustaceans, Egg, Fish, Peanut, Celery, Mustard, Sesame, Sulphite, Nuts, Soy, Lupin, Milk, Molluscs)
```

This query should contain a keyword `VALUES` in it.

Something like,

```
INSERT INTO People (name) values ('Salutation')
```

You should consider following an article from [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) blog about insert query.

Comment: *"Your insert Query is incorrect"* - More like "incomplete". I think you should have waited. And why an MS article? That doesn't use MySQL, it uses MSSQL which isn't what the question was tagged as. Edit: This comment as per the original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44485338/1

Comment: They also want to insert from `<select>` and checkbox values. The question is both too broad but mostly unclear.

Comment: can you enter multiple values?

Comment: In a single insert query, you can insert data for only one row.